# Snowflake: argument 1 to function SYSTEM$ABORT_TRANSACTION needs to be constant

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The snowflake statement:

```
select system$abort_transaction(id) from values (10) as transactions(id);
```

Throws an SQL compilation error:

```
SQL compilation error: argument 1 to function SYSTEM$ABORT_TRANSACTION needs to be constant, found 'TRANSACTIONS.ID'
```

Is there a workaround or it should be fixed by snowflake devs?

UPD: I should have provided more context earlier. What I want to do to abort all active transactions. Something like that:

```
show transactions;
select system$abort_transaction("id"::int) from table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

UPD2:

The following queries are executed just fine:

```
show transactions;
select dateadd(millisecond, "id"::int, current_date()) from table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

Comment: Is this being run as a single statement or in a procedure ?

Comment: "id" needs to be an actual id e.g. select system$abort_transaction(1442254688149); What are you trying to do with this piece of your SQL: " ... from values (10) as transactions(id);" ?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this:
show transactions; 
select system$abort_transaction("id"::int) from table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID()));

Comment: You can dynamically construct abort statements for each transaction but you would then need to copy and paste those statements into the sheet and run them manually. Is this what you are trying to do? If you want to both construct and execute the statements dynamically you would need to so this in a stored proc.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid any manual things, and stored procedures.
I don't understand why system$abort_transaction could not accept the dynamic value as most of the SQL functions that can be used in the select statement.
The question here if it's indeed a snowflake limitation and should be workaround or I missed something and it's possible to run system$abort_transaction with a dynamic value.

Comment: The 2 examples you give in your question have very different structures. One is a single SELECT statement selecting from table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID())) and the other is trying to dynamically generate a select statement by selecting data from table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID())). Even if you dynamically generate a SELECT statement (and your syntax is wrong for doing this) you can’t both generate a statement and execute it in a single step

Answer (score 1):

The problem is self-explanatory from the error message. Try using a variable as the argument (this works for single ids).

```
SET v_id = (select "id" from  table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID())) as t);

select SYSTEM$ABORT_TRANSACTION($v_id);
```

You need to either construct it dynamically using a stored procedure if you want to run for multiple values. It can also be automated by  generating the `SELECT` statements. You would then have to use [**SnowSQL**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html) command line like interface to run the generated script.

Comment: So multiple transactions require stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be with the parameter being passed to the System Control Function `system$abort_transaction()`. As mentioned by @NickW in the comments, the parameter that should be passed is the identifier for the transaction to abort. It appears that `id` in your code is the parameter you passed, whereas this should be a number.

Comment: Yes I understand that, what about this piece of code?

show transactions;
select system$abort_transaction("id"::int) from table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID()));

If I want to abort delete all running transactions?
It does not work. The id column is integer